# Why is IntelliJ IDEA unable to determine java version?

Tags: java, gradle, grails, intellij-idea, wrapper

I'm rather new to IntelliJ IDEA and Grails in general. I just started a new Project, selected my project JDK (11.0.1) and Gradle distribution (4.10.2). Whenever I try to run the project, I get this error:

> Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from
>   '11.0.1'. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java
>   version from '11.0.1'.    at
>   org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:68)     at
>   org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:78)   at
>   org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.checkJavaVersion(ConnectorServices.java:66)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.close(ConnectorServices.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultGradleConnector.close(DefaultGradleConnector.java:57)
>     at
>   org.grails.cli.gradle.cache.CachedGradleOperation.call(CachedGradleOperation.groovy:78)
>     at
>   org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.populateContextLoader(GrailsCli.groovy:525)
>     at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:508)
>     at
>   org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:306)
>     at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:269)   at
>   org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)

All other discussions of the problem I found suggested changing the Gradle distribution, which I already did. I would be so happy if anybody could help me out here.

Cheers!

Comment: Java 11 was released recently so if you have an older version of IntelliJ it has issues. I would make sure you have the latest. e.g. 2018.2.6

Comment: Note: Gradle 4.10.2 was released the week before Java 11, so it might not support Java 11.

Comment: Possibly related https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5120 It suggests 4.10.2 should support Java 11 and an earlier version of Gradle produced this error.

Comment: Is this error specific to trying it in intellij or does the same error also occur when using just gradle (e.g. in your shell)?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you so much for the advice! The error actually occurred while I was using Java 10, I switched to Java 11 in an attempt to solve it. I have the latest versions of IntelliJ an Gradle installed and my Gradle wrapper properties reference the correct distribution. Thanks again, it's probably going to be some simple thing I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

May be your java configuration is not correct. If not correct follow this steps.

1. Goto File-> Project Structure.
2. Change SDK

Or gradle version is not matching jdk 11 then skip this answer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried around with the Project SDK and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issue with Gradle above, if you're trying to run a Grails project I don't think you can do that with JDK higher than version 8.

Even the latest Grails (3.3.8 as of this writing) is still based on SpringBoot 1.5 which does not support newer JDK, I don't know if there's a special trick to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the .gradle directory and restart Intellij.